# ExecuteCommand from VB6 to .net Service

Tags: .net, shell, vb6, windows-services

In VB.net I can execute Custom commands on Windows-Services :

Desktop:

```
Const SmartShutdown As Integer = 12  

Dim myService As New ServiceController("SampleService")
myService.ExecuteCommand(SmartShutdown)
```

Windows-Service:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnCustomCommand(ByVal command As Integer)
```

Is it also possible to execute commands from VB6 to .net Windows-Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ControlService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function to send any control codes.
This does require that you've called [OpenService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684330%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the appropriate access and that your process is running at the required level.
On Vista+, this can be done using the normal manifest (process wide) or [COM elevation](http://hashvb.earlsoft.co.uk/Windows_UAC_and_Elevation#COM%20elevation).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the VB6 [Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk%28VS.71%29.aspx) function and the `sc.exe` command line tool to control windows services, e.g:

```
Shell("cmd /C 'sc stop SampleService > %APPDATA%\svc.log'")
```

**Update**

To send a custom command, e.g.:

```
Shell("cmd /C 'sc control SampleService 128 > %APPDATA%\svc.log'")
```

Custom command should be in the range 128-255.

Comment: Is there also a way to execute custom commands? My service manages Tools using shared dll's. when i install a new version of the main programm, my installer (written in vb6) should check, if any Tools is running.